# MS Dynamic CRM Plugin entity access level

Tags: dynamic, crm

I have a plugin that access an entity.

How do I let the plugin access the global data without changing the user's access level?

Any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want you plugin interact with CRM with top rights you can instantiate IOrganizationService passing null value as user id. Recheck [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservicefactory.createorganizationservice.aspx)